# Cartan and Eilenberg Homological Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

OK, I am looking at Cartan and Eilenberg Homological Algebra book (1956, 1973 printing). Chapter V.9, p97 they define functors T(-,-) of type L$\Sigma$ and R$\prod$. 
T is of type L$\Sigma$, if T(A,C) is a direct sum, whenever A is a direct sum AND C is a direct product. 
T is of type R$\prod$, if T(A,C) is a direct product, whenever A is a direct product AND C is a direct sum.

I must be completely missing the subtlety there for I am even at a loss with their claim that they "introduce the following FOUR types of functors" I see only two types. 
Then Proposition 9.1 (same page) claims that Hom(A,C) is of type R$\prod$ according to the definition they give. 
That is certainly not correct. Now, looking at the proof of this proposition, they assume that A is a direct sum and C is a direct product (and prove that T(A,C) is a direct product, which is correct). 
Did they mean to switch the names for L$\Sigma$ and R$\prod$ and, after that to switch the last direct sum by last direct product in both? 
If this is the error I think it is (and a bad one too), has it been corrected subsequently and where?
If not, somebody kindly enlighten me, I will treat you with a coffee (which I myself may be missing, if I am not seeing this).... Thanks, Rad

Comment: Dear Rad, T is covariant on A and contravariant on C while Hom is contravariant on A and covariant on C.
So Hom is indeed of type R$\prod$. Regards,

Comment: Thanks Makoto, for pointing out that they define it only for (covar,contravar) case. My problem is that I do not see the inner logic in their notation or definitions. Why L$\Sigma$ and R$\prod$? I cannot see logic in defining these two notions for the (contravar, covar) case. They subsequently mention L$\prod$ and R$\Sigma$ and it is only by guessing that I can get an idea what these two should be. Earlier in the text, they have L and R as functors. I imagine L and R should stand for left and right. What I believe is going on is they want to define when functors commute with sums and products

Comment: Is there a list of all the errors in Cartan and Eilenberg? I have come across at least one proof that apparently had an error (Flanders, "Satellites of half exact functors, a correction").

Comment: I am not aware of a list of errors, perhaps because there are not too many errors there